# Javascript: Prevent child class function to be execute from parent function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Parent Class:

```
clicked:function(){
    if(!this.enabled) return;
},
```

Child Override Parent Function:

```
clicked:function(){
    this.parent();
    console.log('Clicked');
}
```

I'm trying to prevent child's function to be execute when disabled using above code but it doesn't works, parent function just stop itself and child keep execute. Is it possible to make parent stop any override code to be execute? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Let's say i have 50 child class which inherit from same class. Is there any simpler way so we don't need to put:

```
if(!this.enabled) return;
this.parent();
```

in each child class clicked function?

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 1):

```
clicked:function(){
    return this.enabled;
} 

clicked:function(){
    if (this.parent()) console.log('Clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parent object you must have a function to check if the parent is enabled or not. The clicked function of parent should be responsible for doing some action .

```
enabled: function() {
    return this.enabled;
}
clicked:function() {
    // this must be responsible for invoking some action
    // do some action
}
```

In the child object you must check if the parent is enabled or not. (This is what you are trying to achieve is guess)

```
clicked:function() {
    if (this.enabled()) console.log('Clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript inheritance is a bit difficult sometimes. Here a small example.

```
// parent class constructor
MMN.Parent = function(text) {
    this.member = text;
}

MMN.Parent.prototype = {
    setMember : function(text) {
        this.member = text;
    }
}

// child class constructor
MMN.Child = function() {
    MMN.Parent.call(this, 'This text is set from the child constructor');
}

// inheritance
MMN.Child.prototype = Object.create(MMN.Parent.prototype);

// override and call of parent method
MMN.Child.prototype.setMember = function(text) {
    MMN.Parent.prototype.setMember(text);
    console.log('this logs from the child method');
}
```

This example shows how to call a parent method in a child class.